# How can i calculate the average per hour?

Tags: excel, time, average

I need to plot my data, but just a value per hour, the problem here is sometimes I have just one value at that hour, but other times I can have 4 our 5 readings at the same hour; so How can I calculate the average per hour?

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming date/times in `A2` down and values in `B2` down try this formula in `C2`

`=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&FLOOR(A2,"1:00"),A:A,"<"&CEILING(A2,"1:00"))`

`FLOOR` function will round down to the hour and `CEILING` will round up so this averages between `01:00` and `02:00` etc.

The above version will give you the average on **every row** (with repeats). If you alter it like this then the average will only appear on the last value for each hour

`=IF(FLOOR(A2,"1:00")<>FLOOR(A3,"1:00"),AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&FLOOR(A2,"1:00"),A:A,"<"&CEILING(A2,"1:00")),"")`

Comment: Good, I thought that the solution would be simple, the problem now, is the floor isnt working with data/times, do I need to create a column to dates and other to hours?

Comment: If they are valid date/times then `FLOOR` should give you a result - perhaps they are text values? Does it work if you use this version with +0 `=FLOOR(A2+0,"1:00")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Pivot Chart.

Drag Date/Time to rows and it will probably automatically group by hours.  If it doesn't you can enable that.

Then drag the Values column to Values, and select to show the Average

[image]